# AlamofireObjectMapper swift 3 REPL & package manager

Tags: swift, alamofire

Question; the easiest way to play with AlamofireObjectMapper

Playground is simply not reliable, Im lookin for alternative way - REPL or other?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks - is it still valid?

Comment: Well, did you try it?  I don't see how anything would have changed with Swift 3.

Comment: You can also use `-framework` to pass in an actual dynamic framework.  I don't think that's mentioned in the linked answer, but appears to be a valid option when running `swift -help`.